# Why does the query plan change dramatically and never complete with a single additional where clause?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, explain

The following postgres query changes quite a bit by a single additional `WHERE` condition. std.a133_findings has an index over (audityear, dbkey), std.a133_findings_augmented has uniqueness constraint over (audit_id, finding_number). After removing/commenting the line, the query never finishes. Can someone explain why?

Postgres Version 13.10 (According to AWS RDS Config panel)

Query:

```
WITH std AS
(
    SELECT
        f.audityear,
        f.dbkey,
        f.audityear::BIGINT *10000000 + f.dbkey::BIGINT AS audit_id,
        COUNT(DISTINCT f.findingrefnums) AS finding_num_count
    FROM std.a133_findings f
    JOIN std.a133_cfda c 
        ON f.elecauditsid = c.elecauditsid
    JOIN std.a133_general g
        ON f.audityear = g.audityear
        AND f.dbkey = g.dbkey
    WHERE split_part(f.findingrefnums,'-',1) = f.audityear::text 
        AND f.audityear >= 2015 
--      AND length(split_part(f.findingrefnums,'-',2))=3 -- ***THIS SINGLE LINE MAKES THE QUERY NEVER COMPLETE***
    GROUP BY f.audityear,
            f.dbkey

), augmented AS(
    SELECT audit_id, count(*) AS  finding_num_count 
    FROM std.a133_findings_augmented aug 
    WHERE audit_id >= 2015::bigint*10000000::bigint
    GROUP BY audit_id 
)
SELECT * 
FROM std s 
JOIN augmented a 
    ON s.audit_id = a.audit_id
WHERE s.finding_num_count > a.finding_num_count;
```

PLAN WITH LINE ABOVE ***COMMENTED***

```
"Hash Join  (cost=388965.30..389257.15 rows=206232 width=48) (actual time=3291.166..3902.305 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((((f.audityear * 10000000) + f.dbkey)) = aug.audit_id)"
"  Join Filter: ((count(DISTINCT f.findingrefnums)) > (count(*)))"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 53505"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1686931 read=20805, temp read=50267 written=50446"
"  I/O Timings: read=588.587"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=372785.83..373053.34 rows=1925 width=32) (actual time=3098.800..3737.144 rows=53506 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: f.audityear, f.dbkey"
"        Buffers: shared hit=1686929 read=18632, temp read=49884 written=50063"
"        I/O Timings: read=547.491"
"        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=372785.83..373010.03 rows=1925 width=24) (actual time=3098.782..3350.856 rows=498377 loops=1)"
"              Workers Planned: 2"
"              Workers Launched: 2"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1686929 read=18632, temp read=49884 written=50063"
"              I/O Timings: read=547.491"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=371785.81..371787.81 rows=802 width=24) (actual time=3093.210..3127.607 rows=166126 loops=3)"
"                    Sort Key: f.audityear, f.dbkey"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5440kB"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=1686929 read=18632, temp read=49884 written=50063"
"                    I/O Timings: read=547.491"
"                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 5648kB"
"                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 6024kB"
"                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=24735.00..371747.12 rows=802 width=24) (actual time=2432.042..2974.816 rows=166126 loops=3)"
"                          Hash Cond: (c.elecauditsid = f.elecauditsid)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=1686915 read=18632, temp read=47745 written=47912"
"                          I/O Timings: read=547.491"
"                          ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using cfda_audityear_dbkey_idx on a133_cfda c  (cost=0.56..334997.57 rows=3203137 width=8) (actual time=2.964..550.853 rows=2561892 loops=3)"
"                                Heap Fetches: 0"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=130749 read=6"
"                                I/O Timings: read=6.118"
"                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=24724.42..24724.42 rows=802 width=32) (actual time=1049.333..1049.335 rows=166481 loops=3)"
"                                Buckets: 65536 (originally 2048)  Batches: 16 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 2752kB"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=1556104 read=18626, temp read=2953 written=6488"
"                                I/O Timings: read=541.372"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..24724.42 rows=802 width=32) (actual time=13.578..906.706 rows=166481 loops=3)"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=1556104 read=18626"
"                                      I/O Timings: read=541.372"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on a133_findings f  (cost=0.00..21435.80 rows=1052 width=32) (actual time=13.542..236.682 rows=166928 loops=3)"
"                                            Filter: ((audityear >= 2015) AND (split_part(findingrefnums, '-'::text, 1) = (audityear)::text))"
"                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 52551"
"                                            Buffers: shared read=15263"
"                                            I/O Timings: read=352.210"
"                                      ->  Index Only Scan using general_audityear_dbkey_idx on a133_general g  (cost=0.42..3.13 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=500783)"
"                                            Index Cond: ((audityear = f.audityear) AND (dbkey = f.dbkey))"
"                                            Heap Fetches: 56280"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=1556104 read=3363"
"                                            I/O Timings: read=189.163"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=15375.97..15375.97 rows=64280 width=16) (actual time=131.110..131.112 rows=94998 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 131072 (originally 65536)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3230kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2173, temp written=210"
"        I/O Timings: read=41.097"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..14733.17 rows=64280 width=16) (actual time=0.029..110.864 rows=94998 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: aug.audit_id"
"              Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2173"
"              I/O Timings: read=41.097"
"              ->  Index Only Scan using a133_findings_augmented_audit_id_finding_number_key on a133_findings_augmented aug  (cost=0.42..12920.16 rows=234042 width=8) (actual time=0.024..70.321 rows=234967 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (audit_id >= '20150000000'::bigint)"
"                    Heap Fetches: 0"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=2 read=2173"
"                    I/O Timings: read=41.097"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '7952056kB', jit = 'off'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1"
"Planning Time: 0.409 ms"
"Execution Time: 3903.403 ms"
```

PLAN WITH LINE ABOVE ***UNCOMMENTED***

```
"Merge Join  (cost=336540.67..352133.16 rows=1071 width=48)"
"  Merge Cond: (aug.audit_id = (((f.audityear * 10000000) + f.dbkey)))"
"  Join Filter: ((count(DISTINCT f.findingrefnums)) > (count(*)))"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..14733.17 rows=64280 width=16)"
"        Group Key: aug.audit_id"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using a133_findings_augmented_audit_id_finding_number_key on a133_findings_augmented aug  (cost=0.42..12920.16 rows=234042 width=8)"
"              Index Cond: (audit_id >= '20150000000'::bigint)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=336540.24..336540.27 rows=10 width=32)"
"        Sort Key: (((f.audityear * 10000000) + f.dbkey))"
"        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=336539.73..336539.98 rows=10 width=32)"
"              Group Key: f.audityear, f.dbkey"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=336539.73..336539.75 rows=10 width=24)"
"                    Sort Key: f.audityear, f.dbkey"
"                    ->  Gather  (cost=1000.98..336539.56 rows=10 width=24)"
"                          Workers Planned: 2"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..335538.56 rows=4 width=24)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..23517.15 rows=4 width=32)"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on a133_findings f  (cost=0.00..23493.40 rows=5 width=32)"
"                                            Filter: ((audityear >= 2015) AND (length(split_part(findingrefnums, '-'::text, 2)) = 3) AND (split_part(findingrefnums, '-'::text, 1) = (audityear)::text))"
"                                      ->  Index Only Scan using general_audityear_dbkey_idx on a133_general g  (cost=0.42..4.75 rows=1 width=16)"
"                                            Index Cond: ((audityear = f.audityear) AND (dbkey = f.dbkey))"
"                                ->  Index Only Scan using cfda_audityear_dbkey_idx on a133_cfda c  (cost=0.56..78005.34 rows=1 width=8)"
"                                      Index Cond: (elecauditsid = f.elecauditsid)"
"Settings: effective_cache_size = '7952056kB', jit = 'off'"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1"
```

Comment: For a answer that is more than guesswork, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` output is required. Also, it would be helpful if you tell us the PostgreSQL version.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the relevant tables? Also why `SELECT DISTINCT` when you already have a `GROUP BY`? And why `COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(f.findingrefnums,''))` is that likely to be differnt from `COUNT(DISTINCT f.findingrefnums)`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I added those (except for ANALYZE on the query that never completes)
@Charlieface I've removed `DISTINCT` and made the `COUNT` modification you mentioned and reran the queries

Comment: The commented out line is expected to eliminate 99.5% of the rows.  Why wouldn't that very different row estimate lead to a very different plan?

Comment: OK. I was expecting maybe filtering those rows and running the same plan. Why does it shift from Hash Join to Merge Join? Sorry, how do I tell that it eliminates that many rows?  But more importantly: why does the query never complete with it's uncommented?

Comment: So after running in other environments, running `ANALYZE` over tables, the query now seems to work.  Very strange.  Sorry for the noise but it appears to be something (temporarily?) quirky with our DB.  Feel free to close.

Comment: Then the solution is probably to tune `autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor` on these tables so that they get analyzed often enough.